# How to generate all permutations of length n given String of length k

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to use recursion to find all n length permutations of a 6-letter string.

For example: given the string "abcd" and n = 3 it'd generate abc, abd, acd, acb, adb, adc, bcd, bca, bac, bad, bda, bdc, etc.

My code currently only generates all string length permutations (6 digit permutations)

```
 public static void printPermutn(String str, String ans) { 

    if (str.length() == 0)
    { 
        System.out.println(ans); 
        return; 
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    { 
        char ch = str.charAt(i); 
        String ros = str.substring(0, i) +  
                     str.substring(i + 1); 
        printPermutn(ros, ans + ch); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @ggorlen it does, thank you! sorry for the repeat question